# Update XML data in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xpath

I need to update the `abc_NumberOfHoldDays` value to empty as shown below. I'm not able to run the query - can someone help me check the query to update the XML data?

**XML**:

```
<Plans>
<Plan>
  <Coverages>
        <Coverage>
          <Answers>
            <AnswersList>
              <Entry key="abc_NumberOfHoldDays" type="System.String">
                <value>11</value>
              </Entry>
 </Coverages>
  </Coverage>
 </Answers>
 </AnswersList>
</plan>
<Plan>
  <Coverages>
        <Coverage>
          <Answers>
            <AnswersList>
              <Entry key="abc_NumberOfHoldDays" type="System.String">
                <value>12</value>
              </Entry>
 </Coverages>
  </Coverage>
 </Answers>
 </AnswersList>
</plan>
```

My query:

```
DECLARE @COUNT INT
DECLARE @xml xml

SET @COUNT = (SELECT Data.value ('count((/*/Plans/Plan/Coverages/Coverage/Answers/AnswersList/Entry[@key="abc_NumberOfHoldDays"]/value))', 'INT') FROM  table1)

SET @xml = (SELECT Data FROM table1)

--SELECT @COUNT
--SELECT @xml

WHILE @COUNT > 0
BEGIN
    SET @xml.modify('replace value of (//Plans/Plan/Coverages/Coverage/Answers/AnswersList/Entry[@key="abc_NumberOfHoldDays"][sql:variable("@COUNT")]/text())[1] with 
    (
       (/Plans/Plan/Coverages/Coverage/Answers/AnswersList/Entry[@key="abc_NumberOfHoldDays"][sql:variable("@COUNT")])[1] =''   
    )
')
    SET @COUNT = @COUNT - 1;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it is needed to use double quotes.

```
declare @xml xml='
<Plans>
<Plan>
  <Coverages>
        <Coverage>
          <Answers>
            <AnswersList>
              <Entry key="abc_NumberOfHoldDays" type="System.String">
                <value>11</value>
              </Entry>
 </AnswersList>
 </Answers>
  </Coverage>
 </Coverages>
</Plan>
<Plan>
  <Coverages>
        <Coverage>
          <Answers>
            <AnswersList>
              <Entry key="abc_NumberOfHoldDays" type="System.String">
                <value>12</value>
              </Entry>
 </AnswersList>
 </Answers>
  </Coverage>
 </Coverages>
</Plan>
</Plans>';

SET @xml.modify('
replace value of (//Entry[@key="abc_NumberOfHoldDays"]/value[1]/text())[1] with ""
');
select @xml;
```

Or it is possible to remove the "value" elements completely.

```
SET @xml.modify('delete //Entry[@key="abc_NumberOfHoldDays"]/value');
select @xml;
```